# Почему в Task приходит неверный параметр?

Tags: c#, task, параметры

Начал изучать работу с Task в C#, т.к. есть у меня задача, где в цикле делаются достаточно длительные запросы через Web API к сторонним сервисам, а потом результаты заносятся в базу данных. Хотел распараллелить выполнение этих запросов через Tasks, но оказалось не все так просто. Даже простейшая тестовая задача по передаче параметров в Task поставила в тупик.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    Console.WriteLine("Start");

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => printIdx(i)));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Begin waiting");
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("End waiting");
}

static void printIdx(int j)
{
    Console.WriteLine(j + "\tstart");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine(j + "\tend");
}
```

Результат выполнения такой:

> ```
> Start
> Begin waiting
> 3 start
> 3 start
> 3 end
> 3 start
> 3 end
> 3 end
> End waiting
> ```

Получается, что фактическая передача значения параметра происходит уже после окончания цикла. Подскажите, как правильно передавать параметры в таком случае?

Comment: У вас проблема в замыкании, а не в Task

Comment: Это понятно, что с Task все хорошо, мне не понятно, что я упускаю?

Comment: Вам уже ответили, нужна переменная, которую извне никто не меняет

Comment: Когда таск фактически стартует, в `i` уже лежит другое значение

Comment: Если вы работаете с `Task`'ами, переходите на async/await, и используйте [`async Main`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-1#async-main).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте копию вашей переменной

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var t = i;
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => printIdx(t)));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Только непонятно почему нужно делать копию переменной?

Comment: @Advarus `i` меняется с каждым циклом, и на момент запуска тасков становится равна 3. `t` не меняется извне и на момент запуска тасков каждый из тасков будет ссылаться на отдельное локальное значение. Не претендую на академичность)

Comment: @Advarus, Почитайте про [замыкания.](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2010/04/c.html)

Comment: спасибо за ответы, буду углублять знания по замыканиям :)

Comment: @maxwell, спасибо за ссылку, там как раз описан подобный случай

Comment: @Advarus: Если ответ решает вашу проблему, поставьте зелёную галку слева.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо за подсказку!